# What is the use of operator<?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In the code snippet below, please, if someone can clarify what is the function of `bool operator<...` and why it is used as a function?

```
bool operator<(const RankedFace& other) const
{
  if (lastDelay == other.lastDelay)
    return face.getId() < other.face.getId();

  return lastDelay < other.lastDelay;
}
```

Comment: It's an overload of the operator `<`, which returns a `bool` (just like the builtin operator `<` does).

Comment: First of all clarify what research material you have read so far, and precisely what you didn't understand about what you read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the (in class) definition of the `operator<` for a user defined type (`RankedFace` I guess).

Thanks to that code, you will be able to compare two objects of type `RankedFace` with the `<`, e.g. `if( r1 < r2 ) // do something...`

Answer (score 2):

It gives the type `RankedFace` a less-than comparison (`operator<`). As declared; it looks like a member method. It could also have been a non-member method with the following signature;

```
bool operator<(const RankedFace& lys, const RankedFace& rhs)
```

It is typically required for use in the standard library associative containers ([`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) etc.).

The associative containers require a comparator to order the objects in them. A custom comparator can be used, but the standard one is [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) which is simply a `lhs < rhs`.

It allows client code to use the less than comparison on objects of that type (`face1 < face2`). It is often (not always) implemented together with other comparators (`==`, `!=`, `<=` etc.). If `operator<` and `operator==` have been implemented, the remaining ones can be implemented using [`std::rel_ops`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/rel_ops/operator_cmp).

Answer (score 1):

This is `RankedFace`'s [less than operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Relational_operators). It compares two `RankedFace` objects. For example:

```
RankedFace foo;
RankedFace bar;

cout << foo < bar ? "foo is smaller than bar" : "bar is greater than or equal to foo";
```

In the code above `foo < bar` causes C++ to call `foo.operator<(bar)`.

Dissection of `RankedFace::operator<` reveals that it:

1. Considers the object with the lower `lastDelay` member the smaller object
2. For objects with identical `lastDelay`s it considers the object which returns a lower `getId()` the smaller object.

An actual in code comparison between `RankedFace`s may not exist. The motivation for implementing the less than operator may have been that the less than operator is required to use a `RankedFace` as in the key in any [associative container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Associative_containers) or [unordered associative container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Unordered_associative_containers).